# How to add boxed text at bottom of first page?

Tags: floats, pdftex, fbox

I need to add some boxed text at the bottom of the first page. If placed anywhere on the first page the box should appear at the bottom of the first page. Please help me. I tried the following code

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]%this generates some dummy text

  \vfill\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\columnwidth-15pt}{
  university Name

  Field of study

  www.rt.de

  Eone by: My name

  E-Mail-Adresse: myemail

  supervisor1:

  supervisor1:

  supervisor1:}} 

    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

> Acutal output

[image]

> Expected output

[image]

Comment: Is `\begin{figure}[b]` what you want?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489813/how-to-add-boxed-text-at-bottom-of-first-page#comment1237951_489813), you can achieve this with a floating environment like `figure` with the `[b]` option. I also edited the width of your `\parbox` to be exactly the line width and replaced the many single word paragraphs in the box by a table, which should better suit this situation.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
    \noindent\fbox{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                university Name \\
                Field of study  \\
                www.rt.de   \\
                Eone by: My name    \\
                E-Mail-Adresse: myemail \\
                supervisor1:    \\
                supervisor1:    \\
                supervisor1:    \\
            \end{tabular}
        }%
    }
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: is it possible to place the box at right side of the page.

Comment: @Shalu You mean like when you put `\lipsum[1-4]` before `\begin{figure}`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `\newpage`.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]%this generates some dummy text

  \vfill\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\columnwidth-15pt}{
  university Name

  Field of study

  www.rt.de

  Eone by: My name

  E-Mail-Adresse: myemail

  supervisor1:

  supervisor1:

  supervisor1:}} 
\newpage
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!! With `page south west` of Ti*k*Z we could expect the same output, isn't it?

Comment: @manooooh Yes and no. You have to make sure by hand that there is enough space, so I do not really see an advantage of adding an overlay picture here.

Comment: @manooooh Thankyou for your response, I do not want this white space. how I remove this white space if I use the command \newpage it will case the white space